# How to all rows that match in many to many relationship

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many

I have the following tables...

```
CREATE TABLE pet_owner (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  last_name  varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  phone_number varchar(50) UNIQUE,
  address varchar(255)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE pet (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  breed varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  weight numeric(5, 2),
  date_of_birth date,
  date_of_death date,
  address varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE pet_petowner (
  pet_id REFERENCES pet,
  owner_id REFERENCES pet_owner,
  PRIMARY KEY (pet_id, owner_id)
);
```

I inserted to my tables `pet`, `pet_owner` and then inserted using the `id`'s into `pet_petowner`. Question I have is how do I now do a query for all the `pets` a `owner` has or all the `owners` a `pet` has.

So far what I've got is the following...

```
SELECT
  pet.id AS id,
  pet.first_name AS first_name,
  pet.last_name AS last_name
FROM
  pet_petowner owner_pet
  JOIN pet pet ON (owner_pet.pet_id = pet.id)
WHERE
  owner_pet.owner_id = 3;
```

This works but I want to also have a column where it shows the owner's first name too, but I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The owner first name is in the `pet_owner` table. If you want a column from that table then you need to add it to the join list.

```
select
  pet.id as id,
  pet.first_name as first_name,
  pet.last_name as last_name
  po.first_name as owner_first_name
from
  pet_petowner owner_pet
  join pet pet on (owner_pet.pet_id = pet.id)
  join pet_owner po on (po.owner_id = owner_pet.owner_id) 
  
where
  owner_pet.owner_id = 3;
```

NOTE: Not Tested